# Where should I put the other files of my command?

Tags: command, path

I made an script with Python, made it executable, and put it in `/usr/local/bin/`. However I have many other files that related to my command, where should I put them? I tried to put them in `/usr/local/` but it doesn't work.

```
from: can't read /var/mail/lib.arguments
from: can't read /var/mail/lib.shot
from: can't read /var/mail/gui.main
/usr/local/bin/shot: 6: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

The error seems to be weird, I didn't put any files in `/var/mail/`.

I also tried to move the whole project to `/usr/local/` and make an symlink of the `main` file and move the symlink to the `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

```
ln -s main /usr/local/bin
```

---

Incidentally I am using Ubuntu.

**Update:**

I change the `shebang` from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/usr/bin/python3`. I moved to my project directory, made a copy of my `main.py` file, renamed it to just `main`. And finally I made a symlink again at `/usr/local/bin`.

---

**My problem is that the file have gray background red name, and I can't call the command.**

Comment: what sorts of files are they? Python modules, configuration files...?

Comment: @ilkkachu **Python files and directories.**

Comment: It looks very much like you are running the file with a shell interpreter (such as `/bin/sh`) rather than a python interpreter. Did you add an appropriate shebang line? How exactly are you executing the script?

Comment: @steeldriver **I added shebang `#!/bin/sh` at the first line of `main.py`. I want to be able to run the command like any other command.**

Comment: You should use an appropriate **python** shebang instead - such as `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @steeldriver **Thanks, but still not working. I updated my question, please give a look.**

Comment: @steeldriver, why are you writing everything in **bold**?

Answer (score 0):

Check `man ln`.

```
ln -s main /usr/local/bin/yourscript
```

Don't give the link the name of the `/usr/local/bin` directory. Name it a file in the directory of your choice.
And perhaps be aware that you are putting a script into the binary directory. That's not really clean.

Edit: Python can be a bit of a weirdo with what gets put into to the `bin` directory. Most things are not really binaries and are also not links to binaries. Often it's just a small Python script which imports itself.
Just check some of them out. For example `pydoc` puts the following in `/usr/bin/pydoc`:

```
1   #!/usr/bin/python3.8
  1
  2 import pydoc
  3 if __name__ == '__main__':
  4     pydoc.cli()
```

You don't need to put it into a `bin` directory if you just want to run a Python script.

- If you want to call it from another program, you can extend the `PATH` to the directory its in, eg. with `PATH=$PATH:/MY/PATH`. Be aware that some programs use their own path variable. Make sure to have a look at the `environmental variables`. For Python, have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#using-on-envvars), and you will find Python is using `PYTHONPATH`.
- In `bash` you can just define an `alias=myscript`.

Comment: **It is still not working. still red and gray file. I copy `main.py` to `main`, `chmod +x main`, and then `ln -s main /usr/local/bin/myscript`**. Is that correct ?

Comment: To give better advice, it would be very helpful if you could provide an example of what you `main.py` does.
Edit: the `.py` or not is not important.